# How to remove maximum time / turn victory condition?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

it's my first civilization game. My game suddenly end when it has reached max turn. How to disable the maximum time / turn from the game? I can't find the setting in my game setup.

Comment: Just click the "One... More... Turn..." button on the victory screen

Comment: in my case the "One... More... Turn..." button is disabled and I don't know why

Comment: There's a setting if you go into the advanced options when creating your game. However, I don't have the details on-hand to create a good answer.

Comment: I've tried advanced settings and uncheck all victory conditions except domination, but time victory still listed on game details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/65980/discussions/0/619569608654517832/

1) go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization Beyond Earth\assets\Gameplay\XML\GameInfo and here you'll find mulltiple xml files that control different aspects of the game

2) In the CivBEVictories.xml look for the line:

```
<Permanent>true</Permanent>
```

Change the true to false, making sure to change nothing else. You can use a simple text editor, just remember to "save" it after the change. Now you'll be able to see the previously hidden option to enable/disable the Time Victory in the advanced settings during setup.

Remember to also disable Max Turns